# My math.pow is return NaN when I call it on an array with numerical values. How do I get the square of an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function with an array of numbers, I want to square it but I want them in the array box like [4,9,16] Each time i try to do that, it throws back a NAN output in the console. The numbers come back listed as in a straight line.

```
digit = (num) => {
  let digits = String(num).split('').map(Number);
  for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    let square = Math.pow(digits, 2);
    console.log(square);
  }
};
digit(234);
```

output : NaN

```
digit = (num) => {
  let digits = String(num).split('').map(Number);

  for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    let square = Math.pow(digits[i], 2);
    console.log(square);
  }
};
digit(234);
```

output : 4
9
16

Is it possible to have my output as [4,9,16]?

Comment: You can't pass an array to `Math.pow` as in your first example. You could return the result of a `map()` on digits. `return digits.map((digit) => Math.pow(digit, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is to modify the array in place, so you need to assign the result of `Math.pow()` to each element of the array.

```js
digit = (num) => {
  let digits = String(num).split("")
  .map(Number);
  for(let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    digits[i] = Math.pow(digits[i], 2);
  }
  console.log(digits);
};
digit(234);
```

After the for loop is done, then each array item will be squared.

Answer (score 0):

Math.pow() expects two inputs, both of which should be numbers (not arrays)

You need to loop through your digits, and push the values to an array.

Something like this:

```
function digit(num) {
    let digits = String(num).split('')
    .map(Number);
    let square = [] // Define an empty array outside the loop
    for(let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
        square.push(Math.pow(digits[i],2)); //Push each value to the loop
    }
    return square; //Return the modified array after the loop
}

console.log(digit(234)); //Outputs [4, 9, 16]
```